# Issue with enter user name and password

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access website, which is asking user name and password.I am facing this issue only in chrome. For firefox switch is working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RyeH.png)

```
 driver.navigate().to("https://t...............");
    driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("@@@@@" + Keys.TAB + "******");
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
     OR
       Robot robot = new Robot(); 
       robot.delay(1500);
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
```

Comment: you need to put username and password like this 'http://username:password@www.website.com'

Comment: tried. but not working

Comment: @ DebanjanB none of given solutions are working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();

alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("username", "password");

alert.Accept();
```

Comment: not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("URL");
 Robot rb = new Robot();

 //Enter user name by ctrl-v
 StringSelection username = new StringSelection("username");
 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);            
 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

 //tab to password entry field
 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
 rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
 Thread.sleep(2000);

 //Enter password by ctrl-v
 StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection("password");
 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);
 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

 //press enter
 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
 rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Using robot classes you can handle popup.

Hope this will help you!!!

Try this:-

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.navigate().to("http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");
```

Comment: This is working firefox browser. I need for Chrome browser.Please remove URL from your previous comments

Comment: ok i will post for chrome browser.